# Is Chuck McGill mentioned at all in Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

Is Chuck McGill, brother of Jimmy McGill (aka Saul Goodman), mentioned at all in Breaking Bad?

Chuck is an important figure in the life of Jimmy McGill in the first season of Better Call Saul, but I don't remember him being mentioned in Breaking Bad.

Comment: The powerful law firm of HHM is also not mentioned in Breaking Bad, so I think we have to wait and see what happens to Hamlin, Kim and Chuck... It's still early in the series!

Answer (score 12):

Apart from Saul's real name, that he reveals to Walt in his very first episode of *Breaking Bad* we know literally nothing about his past, so it's quite obvious that Chuck isn't mentioned.
There is also no *Breaking Bad* episode reference in the [Chuck's page on Breaking Bad Wiki](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Chuck_McGill).

Comment: I wonder if there are cases where Chuck isn't mentioned by name, but Saul references something vague (that we can infer he has experience with) that we can now connect to Chuck.

Comment: We also know that [his step-father slept with his second wife](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110788/saul-goodmans-second-wife)

Answer (score -1):

I think he actually shows up for one second. I'm rewatching Breaking Bad, in season one episode 3 at 40:15 he shows up taking groceries out of his car.

Comment: Can you do screen shot or have more compelling evidence?

Comment: No, 98% sure that is not Michael McKean

Comment: Picture or didn't happen :)

Comment: @Yorik even if it isn't MM, doesn't matter much since he obviously hadn't be cast, maybe not even named yet, but it could still be prelude to the idea of Jimmy having a brother...