# Saul Goodman's Second Wife

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

In Breaking Bad season 3 episode "Green Light", Saul mentions: "I caught my second wife screwing my stepdad, okay? It's a cruel world, Walt."

In Better Call Saul, I have not seen anything about this.

Could it be something that Saul made up to calm Walt down?

Comment: Well he's not married yet in BCS, so it's no surprise we haven't seen anything about his second wife, but of course there's still time.  It's also possible he's lying, of course, or drawing from a fake history he created to support the Saul Goodman identity.

Comment: @Steve-O IIRC there's a reference to his first marriage early on in the show, and the most recent season adds even more info.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Was there any reference to his marital status during his Slippin' Jimmy days?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jimmy AKA Saul Goodman, did not lie to Walt about Jimmy having a second wife. Jimmy's second wife was indirectly mentioned in *Better Call Saul* S05E07, "JMM". In the scene where Jimmy and Kim Wexler (who is Jimmy's third wife as of that same episode) were applying for their marriage license, there was this dialog (emphasis mine):

> Court clerk: Sir, do you have documentation of your **two** previous dissolutions?
> Jimmy: Yeah. [Jimmy hands over the documentation.]

This dialog was probably added to address Saul Goodman's mention of his second wife in *Breaking Bad*. From a Jan. 2018 *Screen Rant* article, "[One Change Vince Gilligan Would Make To Breaking Bad](https://screenrant.com/breaking-bad-better-call-saul-vince-gilligan-plot-hole/)", where Vince Gilligan was interviewed:

> **Breaking Bad**/**Better Call Saul** creator Vince Gilligan has revealed one detail from the parent show he wishes he could change in light of the prequel.
> ...
> *Screen Rant* recently talked with Vince Gilligan, the creator of both shows, about the writing process for *Better Call Saul*, particularly in regard to the canon of *Breaking Bad*. After detailing how the Jimmy/Gus paradigm caused several blocks in the writer's room, the showrunner revealed a more obscure roadblock that he's yet to be able to get around - Saul's two failed marriages:
>
> > "I'll tell you a tricky one. Off the top of my head, there was some casual reference Saul Goodman made way back in Breaking Bad about being married twice or three times or something like that. That one has bedeviled us for sure. It was just a goofy throwaway line in an episode of Breaking Bad where Saul Goodman talked about his second wife or some such and that has bedeviled us. We're trying to figure that one out. When did he a wife? And who was the second wife? Who was his first wife? Blah blah blah. That was a tricky one."

Comment: You can't say it's entirely true since, as far as we know so far, Saul never had a stepdad. All we've been told is that Saul's real father died and his mother raised him and Chuck by herself.

Comment: @arkon Yeah, Jimmy having a stepdad is iffy. But him having a second wife isn't.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of *Better Call Saul* season one, Jimmy tells the story of Chet, who slept with one of Jimmy’s wives, and [fell victim to a Chicago Sunroof](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi0NKXT_xA8&t=70s) perpetrated by Jimmy.

Jimmy doesn’t refer to Chet as his stepfather, but this incident directly led to Jimmy moving to Albuquerque and taking the HHM mail room job, so unless Jimmy got married after leaving Chicago (along with passing the bar in his spare time on his third attempt), Chet is presumably the stepfather in question.